# How to check Sitecore.xDB.base in license file?

Tags: upgrade, licensing

I am upgrading Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1. In Sitecore 8.1 `Sitecore.xDB.base` key is required.

So how can i check that `Sitecore.xDB.base` key is exists in license file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to check if your license does have the XDB enabled or not.

Steps are login to your content editor and then click on the RED top left side hamburger menu as shown in below image.

Then click on license

on opening model window scroll down all the way below where you will see entry named like sitecore.xdb.base and date. as show below in image.

If you do not see entry with XDB that means your license is not XDB enabled

[image]

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Mrunal

Answer (score 5):

It is actually as straight-forward as you might have guessed: all you need to do is open up your license file and search for the text `Sitecore.xDB.Base` (case-insensitive). If you get a hit, then your license has an xDB Base key.

Comment: then my license file have "Sitecore.xDB.Base" key, but after upgrading 8.0 to 8.1, i am facing issue of "The layout for the requested document was not found". any idea why this error is coming?

Comment: Those two things are likely independent of one another. If you open up your logs, you should see a message on startup saying something like "Valid xDB License is Present". Your "layout not found" error is likely due to some other issue. I would start by investigating your Presentation Details. If you are still having trouble, I recommend asking for additional debugging help in the Sitecore Community Slack or else posting a separate (non-broad) question on Sitecore StackExchange for your second issue.

Comment: Thanks Zachary. regarding issue of "Sitecore.xDB.Base" key, "Valid xDB License is Present" is not available in my log file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following method to retrieve license info related to xDB:

`bool xDBAvailable = Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.License.HasModule("Sitecore.xDB.Base");`