# Sitecore Analytics Buttons in the launchpad

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, launchpad

In a Sitecore environment, Sitecore 8.2 update 4, the analytics buttons in the launch pad are hidden. This is what I would expect if analytics were disabled (Xdb.Enabled = false) but analytics are enabled.

Then I thought maybe Sitecore couldn't reach Mongo, so I took a different environment where analytics works, I changed the Mongo connection strings to something that was no good, but the analytics buttons are still visible.

Also, the user I am logged in as is an Administrator, so I dont think its a permissions problem.

What else would cause these buttons to be hidden?

[image]

Comment: Does your license include xDB?

Comment: Good question. It looks like no. I believe the license item I am looking for is Sitecore.xDB.Base?

Comment: Yep it is. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/how-to-check-sitecore-xdb-base-in-license-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidating all the possible reasons behind missing Sitecore Analytics Buttons on Launchpad in this answer:

1. As Mark said please check if your [license file have appropriate xDB License](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/how-to-check-sitecore-xdb-base-in-license-file).
2. Please check of the xDB is not disabled. Open `Sitecore.XDb.config`  and check `<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />` and `<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />`
3. Using `showconfig.aspx` check if any custom patch file is nor overriding the `xDB.Enabled` flag.
4. Lastly check if you are logged in as Administrator or as a user who is not restricted to access to Sitecore Analytics.