# Sitecore 9.3 forms Robot Detection Steps

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am starting with Sitecore Forms. When I am going to create new form, I have a message on the top **"You must have Sitecore xDB installed and robot detection in Experience Analytics configured to enable robot detection"**

I have xDB installed and Added Ip addresses for robot to ignore.
**What else I need to do to make this message go away.**

**Also this is a VM that doesn't have any outside connectivity.**

I can create new forms but robot detection checkbox is disabled. I am using Sitecore 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error couple of days back and in my case, it turned out to be:
`Analytics.AutoDetectBots` was set to `false`. I just changed this setting to `true`.

Couple of more things to check:

1. Check if you have a valid XDB license: [How to check Sitecore.xDB.base in license file?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/how-to-check-sitecore-xdb-base-in-license-file)
2. Open `<CM_Host>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and check below configs:

- `Xdb.Enabled` should be set to true.
- `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` should be set to true.
- `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` should be set to true.

3. Ensure that your layouts contain the [VisitorIdentification](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-the-web-analytics-tracking-feature.html) tag: `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()`

Comment: Thank you. On mine I had Xdb.Tracking.Enabled to false. Setting that to true solved this for me.